# Obtaining the frequency and phase spectra from fourier transform?

Tags: fourier-transform, homework, phase, amplitude

For a question on my homework, I am given `f(t) = e^(-a*abs(t))` and asked to find the Fourier transform of the function. I understand how to do that part, but then the answer requires me to "Compute the amplitude and phase spectra" of the function. My question is, what are these spectra and how do I obtain them from the given function or its Fourier transform?

Answer (score 1):

They simply are the magnitude and angle of the Fourier transform.